# react leaflet vector layers (polygon) with unknown amount of points

Tags: reactjs, react-leaflet

I want to create polygon like that: https://react-leaflet.js.org/docs/example-vector-layers
but here coordinates are hardcoded, In my example i dont know how much coordinates i will have. I tried to use map function like this but it doesn't work:

```js
const polygon = data.map( el => {
        return '['+el.coordinates[0]+ ','+el.coordinates[1]+'],'
    })

    const multiPolygon = [
        [
            polygon
        ]
      ]
```

does somebody has any suggestion?

Comment: I think you need to make a real array instead of string, try `const polygon = data.map(el =>  el.coordinates)` or `const polygon = data.map(el =>  [el.coordinates[0], el.coordinates[1]])`